# Where in simplesamlphp set url on which goes redirect from identity provider?

Tags: redirect, drupal, single-sign-on, saml, simplesamlphp

Having Drupal 7 with simplesaml_auth module and simplesamlphp library. 
After going to identity provider and providing credentials I got automated redirect back to /login/sso with lot of get parameters. How do I point simplesamlphp to deal with this url and proceed with logging user in?

Answer (score 0):

Check your meta files, make sure both SP / IDP have the correct meta files. Also check if the module is enable on SimpleSAMLphp